# Is `boost::xtime_get` deprecated?

Tags: c++, boost

I've stumbled across some information indicating that `boost::xtime_get()` has been deprecated since boost 1.34. Is that true? If so, where can I find an authoritative statement to this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite; it's been deprecated since 1.35.

For an authoritative statement, I would turn to the [1.35 documentation for Boost.Thread](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread.html), specifically the section titled [Changes since boost 1.34](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html):

> `boost::xtime` is supported for backwards compatibility only.

As for why this happened, that same bullet point mentions that the DateTime library is used for timeouts. In 1.34, [`xtime`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/doc/html/boost/xtime.html) was documented as a temporary measure:

> [...] it is expected that [`xtime`] (or some other time library) will be provided in Boost as a separate library, at which time Boost.Thread will deprecate its own implementation.

In Boost 1.35, DateTime became that separate library, so Boost.Thread deprecated its implementation.